# Group by in LINQ error DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.\r\nParameter name: input"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Im trying to group a linq query like below but i am getting the above error, i have only found a couple of questions that asked similar but i just cant seem to figure out why i am getting the above error.

```
{
"pallet_identifier": 21125,
"shipment_items": [
  {
    "sku": 123456,
    "expected_qty": 45,
    "description": "Ralph Lauren"
  },
  {
    "sku": 246810,
    "expected_qty": 35,
    "description": "Channel No5"
  },
  {
    "sku": 481216,
    "expected_qty": 25,
    "description": "Tommy Hilfinger"
  }
]
}
```

I have this class that im using

```
public class GoodInWarehouseBM
    {        

        public string pallet_identifier { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ShipmentItems> shipment_items { get; set; }

        public class ShipmentItems
        {

            public string sku { get; set; } 

            public decimal stock_qty { get; set; }

            public string description { get; set; }

        }

    }
```

And here is my LINQ -

```
var entity = (from consighdrs in mi9TestEntities.consighdrs
                          join consigdests in mi9TestEntities.consigdests on consighdrs.consignment equals consigdests.consignment
                          join consigliness in mi9TestEntities.consiglines on consigdests.condestint equals consigliness.condestint
                          join productcodess in mi9TestEntities.productcodes on consigliness.varint equals productcodess.varint
                          join products in mi9TestEntities.products on productcodess.prodint equals products.prodint
                          orderby consigdests.consignment, productcodess.variantcode
                          where consigdests.destination == storeId && consighdrs.status == "T"
                          select new GoodInWarehouseBM
                          {
                              pallet_identifier = consigdests.consignment,
                              shipment_items = productcodess.variantcode.Select(p => new GoodInWarehouseBM.ShipmentItems
                              {
                                  sku = productcodess.variantcode,
                                  description = products.proddesc,
                                  stock_qty = consigliness.issueqty,
                              })
                          }).ToList();
```

I am guessing that the code is not able to group the shipment_items under pallet_identifier, if this is the case could you point me in the right direction of how to group this query as there are a lot of tables in use.

Comment: I don't see "group by" in the query

Comment: You are correct, ive been somewhat silly.

Comment: What variable type is "productcodess.variantcode"? A string, an int?

Comment: That variable is a string.

Comment: I think you're meaning to do "productcodess.Select", not "productcodess.variantcode.Select". If you do a Select from a string variable (like with productcodess.variantcode.Select), you are effectively doing a Select on a bunch of letters.

Comment: @Andrei The query is wrong, Im struggling to get my head around this at the moment

Comment: You're not that far off, I think, so don't beat yourself up too much! The following changes to your query should get you a bit closer, changes are denoted by % percents: shipment_items = productcodess%.Select(%p% => new GoodInWarehouseBM.ShipmentItems
                              {
                                  sku = %p%.variantcode,
                                  description = %p%.products.proddesc,
                                  stock_qty = %p%.consigliness.issueqty,
                              })

Comment: @jdnew18 I cant do .Select on productcodess, perhaps move this to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187938/discussion-between-jdnew18-and-simonr).